# Why does my mainform freeze when I use clear texbox and append text methods "simultanly" ? (multithreading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, textbox, freeze

I have a textbox on my mainform, and a thread running in an other class which is sometimes updating this same textbox by adding some text using `Texbox.AppendText("some text")`. On my mainform, I have a Clear button, which is clearing the texbox when the user press this button, using `Texbox.Clear()`.
But I notice that sometimes, when the user press this clearing button at the same time that the other thread is updating this same textbox, my IHM is freezing for some seconds, and then I can use it again.
I used thread safe invoke methods, like in the [MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) says, but I can't figure why it's not working properly. Here's my code :

// In my main form MainWindow

```
public static MainWindow GetInstance()
{
    if (_IHM_Main == null)
    {
        _IHM_Main = new MainWindow();
    }
    return _IHM_Main;
}   

public delegate void SafeCallDelegate(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, String texte);
public static void AppendText(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, String texte)
{
    if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new SafeCallDelegate(AppendText);
        textBox.Invoke(d, new object[] { texte });
        textBox.AppendText(texte);
    }
    else 
        textBox.AppendText(texte);
}


private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MainWindow.GetInstance().BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MainWindow.GetInstance().textBox3.Clear()));
    }
    else
        textBox3.Clear();
}
```

// In my Class1.cs where the thread is running

```
private delegate void ChangeTextBox(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textbox, String texte);
private void UpdateTextboxRandomly()
{
    MainWindow.GetInstance().Invoke(new ChangeTextBox(MainWindow.AppendText), MainWindow.GetInstance().textBox3, "adding some text");
}
```

Comment: **1.** Why do you invoke method `textBox.AppendText(texte)` in the `AppendText` method inside `if (textBox.InvokeRequired)` branch? I think that this method call is redundant inside this `if` brach. Please, try firstly to delete this method call. **2.** How often does the thread from class `Class1` invokes method `UpdateTextboxRandomly`?

Comment: What is the point of `GetInstance()` in `MainWindow`? Pass the current instance of `MainWindow` to `Class1` and use the public method to update it. Just `[FormInstance].BeginInvoke()` (not `Invoke()`) the method with the new data. The Form already knows which TextBox to update, since you're clearing it in `btn_Clear` (you can `BeginInvoke()` here, but not `Invoke()`). You don't need 90% (bogus statistics) of all this. You could also use the `SynchronizationContext.Post()` method to perform the update through a `SendOrPostCallback`. You didn't specify what kind of Thread you're running.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev : Oops. Thanks, that was a mistake. I've deleted this. It's a Bluetooth thread which is basically reading data from a Bluetooth Stream, and depending on theses datas I update the texbox. It's updating not less than 100ms.
@Jimi : Well, that's true the `GetInstance()` is useless in `MainWindow`. I don't know why I've done this. Thanks
I have made theses modifications (see my next post to see the code), but my form is still freezing. Maybe that's not coming from something else, but for sure, it's freezing when I spam `btn_Clear` while the thread updating the textbox

Comment: In `btn_Clear_Click()`, instead of the `GetInstance()` line, I've written : `textBox3.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox3.Clear()));`

In `AppendText` method : I've deleted `textBox.AppendText(texte);` in the `if` brackets

Comment: @PLB Have you tried to replace `Invoke` with `BeginInvoke` in `Class1.UpdateTextboxRandomly` as @Jimi recommended?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've done like this : 
`MainWindow.GetInstance().BeginInvoke(new ChangeTextBox(MainWindow.AppendText), MainWindow.GetInstance().textBox3, "adding some text");`
Maybe I didn't understand correctly @Jimi answer ? I tried to remove GetInstance from that line and just do `MainWindow.GetInstance().BeginInvoke(new ChangeTextBox(MainWindow.AppendText), MainWindow.GetInstance().textBox3, "adding some text");` , but I got an error on BeginInvoke "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property"

Comment: In `UpdateTextboxRandomly()` you 1) use `[Control].BeginInvoke()`: the method captures the SynchronizationContext, calls `RegisterWindowMessage` to register the callback and then `PostMessage` to enqueue the message, returning state as an `IAsyncResult` 2) Use `SynchronizationContext.Post()` to post the message to a SendOrPostCallback delegate. This method uses `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`. Both are asynchonous. So, you just need the current Instance of the Form and use BeginInvoke() passing an `Action` or `MethodInvoker` delegate that will complete the operation in the UI Thread...

Comment: In `btn_Clear_Click` you don't really need to check `InvokeRequired`, since the event is raised on the UI Thread already. If you `BeginInvoke()`, you don't need `InvokeRequired` (which is used when you're not sure where the call comes from). But **you never Invoke()** (ever). Invoke() is synchronous: in this context, you are risking a complete deadlock. Remove all the rest. You need to pass the current Instance of the Form the the class (or its current `SynchronizationContext`).

Comment: Note (if you read the Docs about it) that `BeginInvoke()` **can** be called from the same thread (the method of course checks for that and acts upon it) and it's used (quite often) to enqueue *actions* that need to be performed asynchronously. While `Invoke()` **can not**.

Comment: The only way I can have no error from the compiler in the `UpdateTextboxRandomly() ` is like this :
`MainWindow.GetInstance().BeginInvoke(new ChangeTextBox(MainWindow.AppendText), MainWindow.GetInstance().textBox3, "adding some text"); `
Is that what you suggest ? Otherwise I can't figure how to do what you told me. Despite using BeginInvoke, my MainForm is still freezing. Manythanks ...

Comment: @PLB **1.** Have you tried to profile you application? UI freezes can be profiled by using JetBrains dotTrace. Try its Timeline profiling mode. It is very useful for finding and solving UI freeze issues. **2.** Frequent updates of the UI can be the reason of UI freezes. Are you able to rewrite your bluetooth thread to make less updates of the UI. You can, for example, buffer data received from bluetooth is some temp variable and send them to the UI once in a second (or less often).

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Thanks for the tool, unfortunatly I haven't Resharper. When the UI is freezing, in debug mode, if I pause, it stops at the line `else TextBox.AppendText(texte);` inside the delegate. 
Fast operations that are updating my UI from the BT thread are already set in a timer at 250ms. It's printing ASCII char in that textbox.
But the problem of freezing occurs only when I clear the textbox from the main (user action) while the textbox is refreshing by the timer at the same time or at least I guess because the breakpoint never stop inside the `if(textbox.invokerequired)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue by using (with the same code) a `RichTextBox` instead of a `TextBox`.
It seems that `TextBox` is not fitted for that serial reception task